# Node.js: JWT with Express - "Invalid Token" Error when verifying

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Just trying to do a basic implementation of signing and verifying a JSON web token with an Express server, but the "verify" function keeps returning an "Invalid token" error.

When pasting the generated token from the '/' route into the jwt.io debugger it initially says 'invalid signature' but when I check the 'secret is base64 encoded' checkbox, the debugger validates the signature, so I've tried base64 encoding/decoding my secret on the signing and verifying end, but nothing worked.

I am currently performing the requests using a VS code extension named "REST Client" that allows you to make requests using a ".rest" or ".http" file, and I am passing "Bearer [token]" to the Authorization header manually. I was also testing using Postman and received the same error. The app is fetching the header via both methods as expected.

```js
const express = require('express')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const user = {
    username: 'test1234',
    email: 'test1234@gmail.com',
    admin: false
  }

  const secret = 'secret'

  jwt.sign(user, secret, (err, token) => {
    req.token = token
    res.send(token)
  })
})

app.get('/verify', (req, res) => {
  // Bearer <token>
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization
  console.log(authHeader)
  if(authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1]
    const secret = 'secret'
    const userData = jwt.verify(token, secret)
    res.send(userData)
  } else {
    return res.send('Please provide a token.')
  }
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:3000 ...'))
```

I'm expecting the payload (userData) to be returned from the '/verify' route, but instead get an "invalid token" error.

**Update**:
The problem was that I was wrapping the value of my authorization header in quotes, ex. Authorization: "Bearer [token]", when it should have not been in quotes, ex. Authorization: Bearer [token].

Comment: What displays in console for authHeader?

Comment: @SuleymanSah "Bearer <token>", as mentioned in the comment above the declaration of the variable. I am currently performing the requests using a VS code extension named "REST Client" that allows you to make requests using a ".rest" or ".http" file, and I am passing "Bearer <token>" to the Authorization header manually. I was also testing using Postman and received the same result. The app is fetching the header via both methods as expected.

Comment: I just tried this code in my local, and it works fine, / route return the token inside response body,  and I use that token in /verify as Authorization header

Comment: Here is the screenshot that /verify route works: https://pasteboard.co/IEZYAoy.png

Comment: Ah! I was passing the value of my Auth header as a string, with single/double quotes (Authorization: "Bearer <token>") when it should have not had them (Authorization: Bearer <token>). It works now. Thanks @SuleymanSah

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was wrapping the value of my authorization header in quotes, ex. Authorization: "Bearer [token]", when it should have not been in quotes, ex. Authorization: Bearer [token].